# Optimizing the c# code nested for loop using parallel

Tags: c#, loops, memory, parallel-processing

I need to optimize below code so it can execute faster, by means using more memory or parallel, currently it is taking 2 minutes to complete single record in Windows 10 64bit, 16GB RAM PC

1. data1 list array length = 1000
2. data2 list array length = 100000
3. data3 list array length = 100

```
for (int d1 = 0; d1 < data1.Count; d1++)
{
   if (data1[d1].status == 'UNMATCHED')
   {
      for (int d2 = 0; d2 < data2.Count; d2++)
      {
         if (data2[d2].status == 'UNMATCHED')
         {
            vMatched = false;
            for (int d3 = 0; d3 < data3.Count; d3++)
            {
                if (data3[d3].rule == "rule1")
                {
                  if (data1[d1].value == data2[d2].value)
                  {
                     data1[d1].status = 'MATCHED';
                     data1[d2].status = 'MATCHED';
                     vMatched = true;
                     break;
                  }    
                }
                else if (data3[d3].rule == "rule2")
                {
                   ...
                }
                else if (data3[d3].rule == "rule100")
                {
                   ...
                }
                 
            }
            if (vMatched)
              break;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: _"currently it is taking 2 minutes to complete single record in Windows 10 64bit, 16GB RAM PC"_ - not sure what this means...what is a record?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, for any kind of performance oriented programming, *avoid using strings*, use more appropriate types, like enum or bools, instead. Another recommendation is to **profile** your code, so you know what parts actually take time.

In the given example there is only one rule presented, so the data3-loop could be eliminated by first checking if this rule exist and only then proceed with the matching.

This matching between items in data1 & data2 essentially pairs unmatched items with the same value. Whenever problems like this occur, the standard solution is some kind of search structure, like a dictionary, to get better than linear search time. For example

```
var data2Dictionary = data2.ToDictionary(d => Tuple.Create(d.value, d.status), d => d);
```

This should let you drastically decrease the time to find a item with a specific value and status. Keep in mind that the code above will throw in case multiple items share the same value & status, and that the dictionary key will not be updated if the item changes value or status.

Comment: Thank you I will try with dictionary option and update the feedback

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid to start everytime the 2nd loop from 0. By keeping last index with "UNMATCHED" inside data2.

It should reduce the complexity.

In the worst case:

Now 1000 * 100000 * 100 iterations: 10000000000

New (1000+100000) * 100 iterations: 10100000